# How to make an android view take the remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a list of input fields with labels to their left for an edit screen. At the bottom there needs to be a set of buttons, which should be aligned centrally.
The labels can have different widths depending on the language, so the EditText views need to span across the remaining space. I am using a grid layout, because I need to have all EditText views aligned to a vertical line at their left.

I have spent half a day now to solve this, but I fail to make progress. The closest I could get to is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Label 1234545"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvHeightLabel"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Some text which is too long that it could fit in one single row"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/etHeight"
        android:layout_width="259dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Label 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvHeightLabel2"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Some text which is too long that it could fit in one single row"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/etHeight2"
        android:layout_width="259dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btCancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btSave"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

This layout looks like this:

[image: Layout set automatically by Android Studio]

It seems to work first, but when the labels exceed a certain size, the EditText view elements grow out of the screen to the right:

[image: EditText views grow out of the screen]

I don't even get why the above solution works for labels, which just grow slightly. The width of the EditText elements is set to 259dp, which was set by Android Studio automatically. (I tried to arrange the EditText views by sizing it with the mouse on the preview on the design screen. Android Studio arranged it automatically at a certain point as given above.)

There must be some property to let a view eat up what is left independent of its content. The text could scroll, I'm ok with that. I feel like I have not understood the layout concept at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding to restrict the flow of the text.

Comment: Where am I supposed to use padding? I understand that adding a padding to the EditText view would just create some space between the view's edges and the text content. How would this solve my problem of making the view all available space horizontally?

Comment: I think you need to fix the width of your grid view columns and give a few more properties like : android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"